# Why does setted index migrate from df copy to the original df?

Tags: python, pandas

I am checking calculations in a dataframe via fucntion that creates a copy of the original dataframe, runs checks and returns boolean as a result. While running checks I add an index level to the dataframe's copy. The problem is that the additional index values appear in the original dataframe but I don't need them there.

```
d0 = {'col1': [0, 1, 1, 2], 'col2': [3,4,7,8]}
d1 = {'a':'e', 'b':'e','c':'f','d':'g'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d0, index=['a','b','c','d'])

def func(df):
    df1 = df
    mapped_index = []
    checks = []
    for idx in df1.index.values:
        mapped_index.append(d1[idx])
    df1['mapped index'] = mapped_index
    df1 = df1.set_index('mapped index', append=True)
    df1 = df1.droplevel(0)
    for col in df1:
        check = df1.loc['f', col] == df1.loc['e', col].sum()
        checks.append(check)
    return all(x for x in checks)

checks = func(df)
print("Checks: ", checks)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Checks:  True
     col1  col2 mapped index
a     0     3            e
b     1     4            e
c     1     7            f
d     2     8            g
```

As you can see in the original df a column named "mapped index" appears. How can I avoid this?

Comment: `df1 = df` doesn't make a copy, use `df1 = df.copy()`

Comment: Note that you could greatly simplify your function. `tmp = df.set_index(df.index.map(d1)) ; tmp.loc[['e']].sum().eq(tmp.loc[['f']].sum()).all()` should work and won't require any in place modification.

Comment: @mozway, thanks for this. I've tried. It works. Your suggested code is much shorter and, I guess, faster. Thumbs up!